# Why metal sphere (conductor) is used in Van de graff as the output terminal, not any other material , specifically any insulator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Why metal sphere (conductor) is used in Van De Graff as the output terminal, not any other material, specifically any insulator?

Comment: The charge is uniformly distributed in a metal sphere. Moreover, the metal sphere conducts so that spherical surface is an equipotential surface.

Comment: @YashasSamaga , Thank you for your reply. What about an insulator material? Does that affect the rate of charge transfer between the terminal output and any other material upon contact?

Comment: In a Van-de-Graff generator, there exists a wire between two spheres through which the charge moves from the higher potential sphere (inner sphere) to the sphere at lower potential (outer sphere). If you were to use an insulator, the charge would clog at the end of the wire which is connected to the outer insulating sphere. This would result in large potentials being built up at one tiny point. In no time, there would be a corona discharge due to the high surface charge density build-up. There is not much use of using an insulator.

Comment: @YashasSamaga , I got your point regarding the distribution of charges in a metallic sphere. My second question is: "If a charged conductor(metallic sphere) is touched to an insulator object(such as a balloon),will the conductor will transfer its charge to that object? if Yes, will that be the case when using an insulator as the output terminal of a van de graff generator? (In other words will the balloon become charged upon contact with the charged insulator ?)

Comment: Yes, some amount of charge is transferred to the insulator but the charge won't spread on the insulator surface rather it will concentrate on one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a Van de Graaff generator is to produce a source of electric charges which are at a high potential relative to the ground - it is an electrostatic generator.

A motor moves electric charges which are on a belt made of an insulator into the inside of the dome which is going to store the charges.
Within the dome those charges are taken off the belt and deposited on the inside of the dome.
If the dome was an insulator those deposited charges would not move and just induce an opposite charge on the outside of a limited area of the dome.
If the dome is made of a metal those deposited charges are free to move to the outside of the dome and distribute themselves all over the dome.
This sequence continues and so more charge accumulates on the outside of the metal dome whilst at the same time raising the potential of the dome.

If a conducting path is made between the dome and the ground no/very few charges would flow if the dome was made of an insulator whereas with a metal dome the accumulated charges would flow from all the dome until the conducting path between the dome and the ground ceased to exist.